# how to delete partially downloaded file Using cefsharp winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I am using [Cefsharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp)'s `DownloadHandler` to implement a download functionality in WinForms. I am able to cancel the downloading file using `callback.Cancel()` method in `OnDownloadUpdated()` method. The problem is that the partially downloaded file is not deleted. I am storing the downloaded files in the "Downloads" folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can just remove the file by yourself after canceling the download. One of the parameters in the [OnDownloadUpdated](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cd934267c65f494ceb9ee75995cd2a1ca0954543/CefSharp/Handler/IDownloadHandler.cs#L27) method is [downloadItem](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cd934267c65f494ceb9ee75995cd2a1ca0954543/CefSharp/Handler/IDownloadHandler.cs#L25) which contains the full path of the file.

Something like this:

```
System.IO.File.Delete(downloadItem.FullPath);
```

Comment: if i use System.IO.File.Delete(downloadItem.FullPath), application gets struck. Even i tried deleting file using threads, but file be deleted only after closing the application. Also application has to be closed forcefully using task manager.

Comment: @SachinSajjangandla The OS probably still has a handle on the file.